# How to do component composition (includes within includes) with EJS and eleventy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, templating-engine, eleventy

I'm using [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.io/), a static site generator to build a website. It supports a lot of templating languages, but [EJS](https://ejs.co/) looks to be the best in that it's "just JavaScript", except, I cannot figure out how to do component composition, or whether it's at all possible. The EJS docs are, let's say, severely lacking.

What I want to achieve is similar to what you'd do in React or Vue with `props.children` or `<slot>`, where you compose components, but it would obviously be done with partials here.

For example, say I had a grid-item partial that accepted sizes it could render at, its tag name and "children", something like:

```
<%- include('../grid-item', {
  size: '50',
  tag: 'li',
  children: ANOTHER-INCLUDE,
}); %>
```

However, even the above example is a bit limiting, so what I'd really like to achieve is something like:

```
<%- include('../grid', {
  tag: 'ul',
}, () => { %>
  <%- include('../grid-item', {
    size: '50',
    tag: 'li',
  }, () => { %>
    <div>ANY MARKUP</div>
  <% }); %>
<% }); %>
```

Is this possible? Am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

Eleventy supports a workaround for this with [Paired Shortcodes](https://www.11ty.io/docs/shortcodes/#paired-shortcodes) for Nunjucks and Liquid, but both of those templating languages seem severely limited, such as you can't even create an object of data.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing and haven't been able to find anything so far. Would love to hear more about this subject.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Javascript Template Functions`](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/javascript/#javascript-template-functions) for this.

I have set up a `components.js` file that gets imported in my `.eleventy.js` config file.
That components file gets passed the `eleventyConfig` object, and then defines components like:

```
eleventyConfig.addJavaScriptFunction("componentName", function(props) { … });
```

Then you can use that function in your js templates, by accessing it via `this`:

```
module.exports = function(data) {
  return `
    <div>
      ${this.componentName(props)}
    </div>
  `;
```

Comment: can you elaborate further? I'm really struggling to understand how these work, and how I can incorporate them within EJS template

Comment: Are you using https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/javascript/?
Read that and this: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/javascript/#javascript-template-functions

Comment: No, I'm using EJS templating, not 11ty.js templating.

Comment: Yeah, so you can use shortcodes/filters/functions with 11ty.js templating, but if you want to stick to ejs then you'd need to use code like in your snippet in the question. Have you tried accepting a function in the parent `grid` file?

Comment: Yeah, I tried unsuccessfully to hook in to the EJS compiler to parse the what I passed to it :(

Comment: The EJS templating is weird, if you want one that's "Just javascript", then go for the .11js templates, every page is just a module, and components can be simple functions